# Hibernate MappingException with inheritance of a concrete non-domain class in Grails

Tags: hibernate, inheritance, grails, mappingexception, concrete-inheritance

#### The Scenario

I have a need to represent an object in two different contexts. One context should not persist and the other should. The persistent objects are actual data pulled from another system. The non-persistent objects represent parts of a product definition. The two will be compared, and I'm not interested in storing the definition data. The persisting object needs to have additional information stored with it.

#### The Implementation

In order to accomplish this, I decided that the most logical thing to do would be to create the base class in the src/groovy folder to avoid grails/hibernate wanting to persist it as a domain class.

```
class Resource{
    String name
    Date lastModified 
}
```

The domain class that I want to persist looks like the following.

```
class OwnedResource extends Resource{  
  Date dateCreated, lastUpdated
  Owner owner
  static belongsTo = [owner: Owner]
  static mapping = {
   //I assumed I would need this so that grails would not expect 
   //to store the object in the base class table that doesn't exist
   tablePerHierarchy true 
   table 'owned_resource'
  }
}
```

Lastly we then have the Owner class which hasMany OwnedResources.

```
class Owner{
  Date dateCreated, lastUpdated
  String name
  static hasMany = [
    resources: OwnedResource
  ]
}
```

#### The Problem

When I run-app, I end up getting a friendly Hibernate exception:

```
2011-10-24 20:32:01,307 [main] ERROR context.GrailsContextLoader  - Error executing bootstraps: 
Error creating bean with name 'messageSource': Initialization of bean failed; nested exception 
is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 
'transactionManager': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'sessionFactory' while setting bean 
property 'sessionFactory'; nested exception is 
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 
'sessionFactory': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is 
org.hibernate.MappingException: Association references unmapped class: OwnedResource

org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 
'messageSource': Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is 
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 
'transactionManager': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'sessionFactory' while setting bean 
property 'sessionFactory'; nested exception is 
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 
'sessionFactory': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is 
org.hibernate.MappingException: Association references unmapped class: OwnedResource
at org.grails.tomcat.TomcatServer.start(TomcatServer.groovy:212)
at grails.web.container.EmbeddableServer$start.call(Unknown Source)
at _GrailsRun_groovy$_run_closure5_closure12.doCall(_GrailsRun_groovy:158)
at _GrailsRun_groovy$_run_closure5_closure12.doCall(_GrailsRun_groovy)
at _GrailsSettings_groovy$_run_closure10.doCall(_GrailsSettings_groovy:280)
at _GrailsSettings_groovy$_run_closure10.call(_GrailsSettings_groovy)
at _GrailsRun_groovy$_run_closure5.doCall(_GrailsRun_groovy:149)
at _GrailsRun_groovy$_run_closure5.call(_GrailsRun_groovy)
at _GrailsRun_groovy.runInline(_GrailsRun_groovy:116)
at _GrailsRun_groovy.this$4$runInline(_GrailsRun_groovy)
at _GrailsRun_groovy$_run_closure1.doCall(_GrailsRun_groovy:59)
at RunApp$_run_closure1.doCall(RunApp.groovy:33)
at gant.Gant$_dispatch_closure5.doCall(Gant.groovy:381)
at gant.Gant$_dispatch_closure7.doCall(Gant.groovy:415)
at gant.Gant$_dispatch_closure7.doCall(Gant.groovy)
at gant.Gant.withBuildListeners(Gant.groovy:427)
at gant.Gant.this$2$withBuildListeners(Gant.groovy)
at gant.Gant$this$2$withBuildListeners.callCurrent(Unknown Source)
at gant.Gant.dispatch(Gant.groovy:415)
at gant.Gant.this$2$dispatch(Gant.groovy)
at gant.Gant.invokeMethod(Gant.groovy)
at gant.Gant.executeTargets(Gant.groovy:590)
at gant.Gant.executeTargets(Gant.groovy:589)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:120)

Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'transactionManager': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'sessionFactory' while setting bean property 'sessionFactory'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.MappingException: Association references unmapped class: OwnedResource
... 24 more

Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.MappingException: Association references unmapped class: OwnedResource
... 24 more

Caused by: org.hibernate.MappingException: Association references unmapped class: OwnedResource
... 24 more
```

Perhaps my implementation is bad practice, since after much googling and searching of StackOverflow, I have yet to encounter anyone facing this same issue or attempting a similar implementation. Most people are attempting to use abstract classes, which does work. I want the class Resource to be concrete because I need to instantiate it. The answer may simply be that grails doesn't allow this functionality, but I'd like to hear a definitive answer and any possible work arounds. I'm leaning toward having to duplicate the class instead of using inheritance.

What am I doing wrong and why is this error occurring? Can this implementation be done in grails?

Answer (score 3):

In this case if you are trying to extending a class that it is outside the domain folder, you should declare that class as abstract.

Otherwise Hibernate will try to map it, and because it´s not in the domain folder everything will eventually blow up.

Comment: My Class which was extended by my domain class was in src/groovy folder and I forgot to make it 'abstract'. Then I added the abstract keyword before the class, it works like majic. Thanks @mgg.

Answer (score 0):

Use abstract base class Resource and then add a 3rd class that extends Resource that is not a domain object but a simple utility class that you can use for other things and not worry about persistence. 
Good luck... 
Dmitry.